# RadScheduler Reminder get description issues

Tags: c#, telerik, radscheduler

I using Telerik RadScheduler Reminder ,when  reminder  is popUp's i  need to check the Name and  description of this event.I find the way to get Name , but i can't get description.I debuged and i see description, but i can't get to it.

Here the picture of the object:

[image]

My code:

```
  private void radSchedulerReminder1_RemindObjectShown(object sender, RadShowRemindObjectArgs e)
        {
            string Subject = e.RemindObject.Subject.Trim();//Name i found.
            string  des = e.RemindObject.GetType().;//here i stuck with description
}
```

Any ideas how to Get the description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but for others that stumble across it:
You can cast the RemindObject as an IEvent and get description:

```
private void radSchedulerReminder1_RemindObjectShown(object sender, RadShowRemindObjectArgs e)
{
    string des = ((IEvent)e.RemindObject).Description;
}
```